# HTACCESS - Redirect multiple parked domains to Different URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

There are 10 different domains names. I would like to redirect some of them to:

```
somedomain1.com, somedomain2.com -> somenewdomainONE.com/en
somedomain3.com, somedomain4.com -> somenewdomainTWO2.com/fr
```

I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?somedomain1.com$ [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?somedomain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomainONE.com/en [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?somedomain3.com$ [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?somedomain4.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.somenewdomainTWO.com/fr [L,R=301]
```

I'm not sure why, but this redirects all domains to http://www.newdomainONE.com/en even when I try accessing somedomain3 or somedomain4.com. I'm also getting a redirect loop depending on what I try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(domain1|domain2)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomainONE.com/en/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(domain3|domain4)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomainTWO.com/fr/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to test in a new browser to avoid old 301 cache.